# Moving ImageView on click of Buttons

Tags: android, android-imageview

I used four buttons (Up,down,Left,Right) and also i have imageview in center. I have to move the image accordingly when i press UP button it should move image in upward direction and when i press left it should move to left and similarly for remaining directions it should move. I have used on click listener to move image. Please check the image attachment for better understanding. Thanks in advance[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If you are target android 4.0 or greater, you can use a property animation and move its x or y value
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

if you are targeting pre 4.0 you can still use animations but with a third party library called NineOldAndoids

http://nineoldandroids.com/

Comment: Thanks @KennyC for your quick reply. I don't want to do any animation just want to move the imageview on click of the buttons.For moving the imageview I tried with Drag and Drop its working fine but now I want to move on click of the Buttons.

Comment: If you don't want to show an animation, just set the duration to 0, it will get the same effect. If you are still very against that, you can call setX(...) and setY(...) on the view, but those methods require api 11 or greater, can not be done before that.